# 7 day rolling sum not working on Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need your help. I'm working on a Power BI project and I'd like to create a Measure that calculates the 7 day rolling sum of my number of sales.

I have a table with several columns. In one of these columns, I have the number of sales per day.

My DAX measure is supposed to sum the number of sales for the day and the 6 days before. And this process is repeated for each date.

The problem is that my code doesn't work. Here's what I have:

```
Actual Orders - 7DR = 
VAR CurrentRow = SELECTEDVALUE(Table[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM(Table[Sales]), DATESINPERIOD(Table[Date], CurrentRow, -6, DAY))
```

The problem is that I also have an Excel spreadsheet with the same calculations made with a simple SUM and my results are not the same.

Do you guys have any idea why it's not working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Other than perhaps an off-by-one error, that measure looks fine.  With this table

```
let
    Days = List.Dates(#date(2023,1,1),20,#duration(1, 0, 0, 0)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Days, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "Date"}}),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Sales", each 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Inserted Month",{{"Date", type date}})
    
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

and this measure

```
Actual Orders - 7DR = 
VAR CurrentRow = SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[Date])
RETURN
CALCULATE(SUM('Table'[Sales]), DATESINPERIOD('Table'[Date], CurrentRow, -7, DAY))
```

You get this

[image]

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response. There is something I do not understand. For a 7 day-rolling measure, sometimes people use -6 sometimes -7. Which one is the best?

Answer (score 0):

Check this one out:

```
7 day rolling sum = 
VAR __LAST_DATE = 
    LASTDATE('Table'[Date])
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        SUM('Table'[Sales]),
        DATESBETWEEN('Table'[Date], DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, -6, DAY), __LAST_DATE)
    )
```